# What is the maximum URL length that Mandrill supports when click tracking?

Tags: mandrill

According to [their documentation](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582897-Why-aren-t-clicks-being-tracked-), Mandrill will not add click tracking to links if they are too long:

> Some internet browsers and email clients break links that are over a certain length. If Mandrill detects that adding tracking information could create links too long for these email programs and browsers, tracking data won't be added

However, they do not specify what the length is.

**Does anyone know what the maximum length allowed is?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this tweet from @mandrillapp](https://twitter.com/mandrillapp/status/502511556945379329),

> URLs longer than 255 bytes won't have click tracking applied.